# Count of positives / sum of negatives Syntax Error

Tags: ruby, algorithm

So I am currently working on the following problem in code wars:

Return an array, where the first element is the count of positive numbers and the second element is sum of negative numbers. If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array.

I came up with the following code, it ain't pretty, but I know it should work:

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(lst)
  pos, neg = 0, 0

  lst.each do |num|
    if num < 0
      neg += num
    else
      pos++
    end
  end

  [pos, neg]
end
```

I then call the following test:

```
count_positives_sum_negatives([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15])
```

and it should return => [10,-65]

However its returning the following error:

```
(repl):11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
(repl):17: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
..., 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15])
...
```

Can anyone give me an explanation of why this is occurring?

Comment: You're issue is `pos++` ruby doesn't have that operator like the C type languages do. Try changing that to `pos += 1`

Comment: " it ain't pretty". Aside from the error, your code looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you both! The operator was the issue. it works great now!

Answer (score 7):

As people have pointed out the error here is `x++` is not valid Ruby, that you need `x +=1` instead. The postfix and prefix increment operator is a point of wild confusion in most languages so Ruby has never implemented one. As in, what is the result of `x++ + x++ + ++x`?

Here's a strategy that's different using [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to first split the array, then collapse that together using `inject`:

```
positives, negatives = list.partition(&:positive?)

[ positives.length, negatives.inject(0, &:+) ]
# => [10,-65]
```

Comment: Clever to recognize that you can partition on `positive?` but not on `negative?`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm missing the significance?  wouldn't it work with `negatives, positives = list.partition(&:negative?)`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn If you partition on `negative?`, then 0 gets grouped with the positives (effectively non-negatives), whereas if you partition on `positive?` then 0 is grouped with the negatives (effectively, non-positives). Technically, 0 should not be included in _either_ grouping, but with the negatives you're calculating a sum, and 0 will have no impact. For the positives, you're calculating a count, and if you include 0s in your count you'll have the wrong answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, so 0 doesn't respond to `positive?` or `negative?` ... wait ... wait...  just tried it and confused myself... where is `#positive?` defined?  It's not a fixnum method... nor is `#negative?` ??

Comment: @CarySwoveland ^ ?

Comment: `Numeric#positive?`

Comment: Well it doesn't work with the test data.  @sagarpandya82

Comment: 0 does respond to `positive?` and `negative?`, it returns `false` in both cases which means when used with `partition` 0 always gets lumped in the not-satisfied-array.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, remember you can use `1.method(:negative?).owner
 => Numeric`. Actually, `4168.method(:negative?) #=> #<Method: Fixnum(Numeric)#negative?>` is enough, as the owner is shown in parentheses (as here) when it's not defined in the receiver's class.

Comment: @CarySwoveland clever!

Comment: @tadman, thanks for your help. I fixed the operator and it works great now! Also, thanks for sharing partition. That is something I will try and use moving forward

Comment: @wnamen The Enumerable library is full of neat tools like that, so do take a little time now and then to at least browse what options you have. There's a method for nearly every occasion and it saves you a lot of trouble in the long-run if you know how they work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way you could do that.

```
def count_pos_sum_neg(arr)
  return [] if arr.empty?
  arr.each_with_object([0,0]) do |n,a|
    a[0] += 1 if n > 0
    a[1] += n if n < 0
  end
end

count_pos_sum_neg [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]
  #=> [10, -65]
```

In actual application, returning a hash may be more convenient.

```
def count_pos_sum_neg(arr)
  return [] if arr.empty?
  arr.each_with_object({count_pos: 0, sum_neg: 0}) do |n,h|
    h[:count_pos] += 1 if n > 0
    h[:sum_neg]   += n if n < 0
  end
end

count_pos_sum_neg [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]
  #=> {:count_pos=>10, :sum_neg=>-65}
```

Comment: Nice, but to nitpick, this answer (and tadman's) is overlooking `If the input array is empty or null, return an empty array`.  Of course, the OP's solution has the same problem.

Comment: Taking a page from @Tadman, the antepenultimate line and the one before could be replaced by `n>0 ? h[:count_pos] += 1 : h[:sum_neg] += n`.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, thanks for pointing that out. I edited. Is "null" different than "empty".

Answer (score 2):

THe problem is `pos++` which is not a valid operation in Ruby.  It's being interpreted as an addition followed by a unary `+` but there's no number after the unary so it's expecting the next line to contain a value.

But the next line is `end` which is unexpected (hence the first error `unexpected keyword_end`) and because the `end` is now consumed you are missing an end for the method (hence the second error `expecting keyword_end`

So just change the line to...

```
pos += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant using [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
def count_pos_sum_neg(arr)
  arr.inject([0, 0]) do |(count, sum), n|
    if n > 0
      [count + 1, sum]
    else
      [count, sum + n]
    end
  end
end
```

Or compressed:

```
def count_pos_sum_neg(arr)
  arr.inject([0, 0]) { |(c, s), n| n > 0 ? [c + 1, s] : [c, s + n] }
end
```

The code doesn't check "If the input array is empty or null".

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected your initial approach which is easy to read and simple, is actually fast too. Some results from a [fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) comparison (code compacted):

```
require 'fruity'

arr = ((-1000..-1).to_a + (1..1000).to_a).shuffle

#various methods etc as defined in other answers.

compare do
  wnamen  { ar = arr; wnamen_method ar  }
  tadman  { ar = arr; tadman_method ar  }
  cary    { ar = arr; cary_method ar    }
  cary2   { ar = arr; cary2_method ar   }
  stefan  { ar = arr; stefan_method ar  }
  stefan2 { ar = arr; stefan2_method ar }
end
```

results:

```
Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
wnamen is faster than tadman by 2.0x ± 0.1
tadman is similar to stefan2
stefan2 is similar to stefan
stefan is similar to cary
cary is faster than cary2 by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0% (results differ: [1000, -500500] vs {:count_pos=>1000, :sum_neg=>-500500})
```

All the other approaches are of course interesting and worth knowing nonetheless.

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize that! Thanks for sharing this information.